# python urllib, returns empty page for specific urls

Tags: python, urllib

I am having trouble with specific links with urllib. Below is the code sample I use:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

url = ""
req = Request(url)
html_page = urlopen(req).read()

print(len(html_page))
```

Here are the results I get for two links:

```
url = "https://www.dafont.com"
Length: 0

url = "https://www.stackoverflow.com"
Length: 196673
```

Anyone got any idea why this happens?

Comment: please specify what do you want

Comment: You have to send certain headers and user-agent strings with your request in order for your request to complete for certain websites.

Comment: I want to understand why this returns empty for the specific link. I am new to python/urllib so is there something I am missing?

Comment: @SanketVyawahare is there any specific way to know which headers etc are needed for a specific url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using. You will get the response. Certain websites are secured and only respond to certain user-agents only.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://www.dafont.com"
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"}
req = Request(url, headers=headers)
html_page = urlopen(req).read()

print(len(html_page))
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a limitation imposed by the authors dafont website.

By default, the urllib sends a User-Agent header of `urllib/VVV`, where `VVV` is the urllib version number. For more see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html Many webmasters protect themselves from crawlers. They parse User-Agent header. So when they come across an User-Agent header like `urllib/VVV`, they think it's a crawler.

Testing HEAD method:

```
$ curl -A "Python-urllib/2.6" -I https://www.dafont.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 15:11:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Content-Type: text/html

$ curl -I https://www.dafont.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 13 Jun 2021 15:12:02 GMT
Server: Apache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=dcauh0dp1antb7eps1smfg2a76; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html
```

Testing GET method:

```
$ curl -sSL -A "Python-urllib/2.6" https://www.dafont.com | wc -c
       0

$ curl -sSL https://www.dafont.com | wc -c
   18543
```

Comment: what does -A option for curl command ? and also is it mandatory to pass -sSL ? thank you !!

Comment: `-A`: set the User-Agent header, `-L`: follow redirects if needed, `-s`: do silent request, `-S:` show an error message if curl fails.